# include string, string doesn't name a type

Tags: c++, string, include

I have included string and just after call a string variable in a struct in an header file.
I get the 'string doesn't name a type' for string Origin and Destination City, despite calling string just before it

```
//sortedListClass.h (a few lines of comments)
#include <string>
struct flightRec{
    int flightnumber;
    string Origin; //problem #1
    string DestinationCity; // problem #2
    float cost;
    flightRec* ptr;
};
typedef flightRec* nodeptr;
#ifndef SORTEDLISTCLASS_H
#define SORTEDLISTCLASS_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
```

> sortedListClass.h:10:5: error:
> ‘string’ does not name a type
>
> sortedListClass.h:11:5: error:
> ‘string’ does not name a type

Might I ask what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called `std::string` unless you put in a `using` directive (which you shouldn't do in a header).

Comment: Ah, yes... I tried string::string instead and it didn't work. Thank you. I forgot it was in std.