# C++ overloaded operator linked sorted list ADT

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, adt

I have been trying to overload the equal (==) and less than (<) operators for a linked sorted list. I am not sure if I understand exactly if what I am doing makes sense. I have a struct with a string variable for DestinationCity, of which these operators have to compare. I have used strcmp in an attempt to make it work. Here is the code:

```
bool sortedListClass::operator <(const flightRec& rhs) const{
    
    
    if (strcmp(flightRec.DestinationCity, rhs.DestinationCity) < 0)
    { // I'm not sure if flightRec.DestionationCity is what I should write.
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;

}
bool sortedListClass::operator ==(const flightRec& rhs) const{
       if (strcmp(flightRec.DestinationCity, rhs.DestinationCity) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Here are the error messages.

> sortedListClass.cpp: In member function ‘bool sortedListClass::operator<(const flightRec&) const’:
> sortedListClass.cpp:185:25: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
>
> sortedListClass.cpp: In member function ‘bool sortedListClass::operator==(const flightRec&) const’:
> sortedListClass.cpp:194:28: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> // I'm not sure if
>   flightRec.DestionationCity is what I
>   should write.

You shouldn't:-). If you want to define `operator<` on some class you do not do this in container class, but in the class which objects you want to compare. Here it would be `flightRec`.

```
bool flightRec::operator< (const flightRec& other) {
   // compare this and other
   if (strcmp(this->DestinationCity, other.DestinationCity))
   ...
}
```

Comment: flightRec is a struct, not a class. I tried to change what you added, but it gave me: 

sortedListClass.cpp:185:50: error: no ‘bool flightRec::operator<(const flightRec&) const’ member function declared in class ‘flightRec’



sortedListClass.cpp:196:51: error: no ‘bool flightRec::operator==(const flightRec&) const’ member function declared in class ‘flightRec’

Comment: @Athetius: a struct and a class in C++ are exactly the same thing. The only difference is that base classes and members are `private` by default if you use `class`, and `public` by default if you use `struct`.

Comment: My code is just a sample. You need to move `operator<` and `operator==` code to `flightRec` and clear these defs from `sortedListClass` etc. It won't work by just pasting the sample I provided.

Comment: @Athetius: possibly your teacher is using (and teaching) a style in which you use the `struct` keyword for classes that you aren't planning to give any significant member functions, any private data members, or any base classes, and `class` for everything else. But style is how you choose to use the language rather than what the language actually is...

Answer (score 0):

If you're [still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452839/include-string-string-doesnt-name-a-type) using `std::string`, don't compare with `strcmp`. `==` and `<` are both defined on `string`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave the 'struct' without members, you can define the binary operator as a non-member:

```
bool operator <(const flightRec& lhs, const flightRec& rhs) 
{
   if (strcmp(lhs.DestinationCity, rhs.DestinationCity) < 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```